# Correct name and technique for 2-5 adjacent strings

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I have been learning guitar for almost 1 year now. I mainly play Rocksmith (don't judge me) and Yousician.

I have been nailing a lot of techniques lately e.g. fingertip muting for power chords and my cowboy chords are sounding really good and clear, however I am having some trouble with one final piece which is playing several adjacent strings without hitting the strings around it.

Some example of this that I have run into:

```
--X--|--X--|--X--|--0--
--X--|--X--|--X--|--0--
--X--|--7--|--X--|--0--
--5--|--7--|--9--|--0--
--5--|--7--|--9--|--X--
--5--|--X--|--X--|--X--
```

Or in Rocksmith:

[image]

Based on my current experience I assume there is a way to mute the G, B and low E strings in this case, however I have not been able to find a way that feels "correct" so far.

What is a good technique for these notes? I think the reason I am struggling is due to having one finger pressed hard and flat against the fretboard to cover these notes which is really restricting the mobility of my other fingers.

Also, do they have a special name that I can use to look techniques up online (the fact that I can't reference them in search makes it hard to look up)?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use hybrid picking - plectrum and fingers together. Especially for this, as you could, for instance, use plectrum/middle/ring fingers for the 3 strings, then move across and do the same, etc.4 strings doesn't need to be problematic, either, just employ pinky. I use this a lot, and it saves muting an in-between string sometimes, say 5, 3 and 2, can be played with plectrum/middle/ring.